# What to do with the token data when the user signs out from android app?

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth, client-server

The questions is pretty simple.I am also a novice regarding token authentication.

I know that, in case of token authentication, in case of android apps, token is used so that the user credentials does not remain in the app.i.e. whenever the user fetches data from server, it does not send the user credentials everytime but he sends token.

When the user signs in for the first time, from the app, a token is generated from the server and is "entried" in the database beside the user data.This token is send back to the app from the server and it is this token that the user, from the app, has to send everytime it plans to fetch some data from the server.When the user has to fetch data, it sends the required parameters and with them the token.This token is matched with all the tokens present in the database.If the token is present,it also gets the user associated with that token.And as the token is present so the user session is valid and then the required data from the server is send back to the android app.

What i want to know is that what to do with the token, in both client and server side, when the user logs out?

If any doubt please comment.I know its a simple question but dont know much about token authentication.Thanks everyone for their time.

Note:- Also if any of my concepts, in the question, is wrong please feel free to correct me.

Comment: You can delete the `token` when user logs out. Its safe. OR you can set an expiry time for the `token` in which user automatically logs out when `token` expires. `Token` expiry will also delete that particular `token` from db.

Comment: You are not mentioned which type of `token` auth you are using.

Comment: @SudheeshR actually I am planning to have the token custom made.Is this ok?

Comment: Of course, it's fine to use your custom tokens. But you have to set an expiry for that tokens. And delete it from db after that expiry.

Comment: @SudheeshR Ok so basically I will delete the token from both the sharedpreference file in the client side and also from server db?

Comment: Yes, you have to delete from both locations if that one `token` is used for all of your communications between client-server

Comment: or you can keep it as long as you prefer. its your choice.

Comment: But remember that all `tokens` have an expiry. Its for security purpose.

Comment: @SudheeshR ok thanks.Please write this as an answer and i will upvote and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all `tokens` have an expiry. This is intended for security purposes. But you can choose whether to set an expiry for your token. But I suggest that you must put an expiry for your `token`. And also delete that `tokens` from both server and client, and set user session to login again. Use `timestamps` to create the `tokens`. They are also useful when comparing `tokens`.

Happy Coding.... :-)